# Is this nasty recursion possible in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, recursion

I have 3 tables:

```
Region
(
    Region_id int,
    Parent_id int,
    Region_name varchar(50)
)

RegionStore
(
    Region_id int,
    Store_id int
)

StoreItems
(
    Store_id int,
    Item_id int
)
```

The Region table is recursive in that regions can have parent regions and if a parent id is null that is a top level region. Regions go to a possible 4 levels.

I need to get an item count for every region at every level. If a region is a parent – I need the count for all its children down as many levels and branches as it goes. In other words if region 255 has parent 130 and 130 has parent 67 and 67 has parent 2 I need a count for 2 (including all children and branches) and a count for 67 including all its children and branches and so on. I need to get this for all regions in one call. Is this possible using recursive query?

Comment: Yes - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: @Yuck - yes I can get the parent child relationship to display just fine (I acutally use a Table Variable in place of a CTE) but it's getting the item counts that I am stuck on. I can get them for the bottom most level - but that is as far as I have been able to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Region TABLE 
( 
    Region_id int, 
    Parent_id int, 
    Region_name varchar(50) 
) 

DECLARE @RegionStore  TABLE
( 
    Region_id int, 
    Store_id int 
) 

DECLARE @StoreItems TABLE
( 
    Store_id int, 
    Item_id int 
) 

INSERT @Region
SELECT 2, NULL, '2' UNION ALL
SELECT 67, 2, '67' UNION ALL
SELECT 130, 67, '130' UNION ALL
SELECT 255, 130, '255' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, NULL, '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 68, 2, '68' 

-- add more test data here

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  
        Region_id,
        Parent_id,
        Region_name,
        Region_id AS Region_id_calc
    FROM @Region

    UNION ALL   

    SELECT  
        r.Region_id,
        r.Parent_id,
        r.Region_name,
        CTE.Region_id_calc AS Region_id_calc
    FROM CTE
    INNER JOIN @Region AS r
        ON r.Region_id = CTE.Parent_id
)
SELECT  
    CTE.Region_id,
    Region_name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Item_Id)
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN @RegionStore AS s
    ON CTE.Region_id_calc = s.Region_id
INNER JOIN @StoreItems AS i
    ON s.Store_id = i.Store_id
GROUP BY
    CTE.Region_id,
    Region_name
ORDER BY 
    CTE.Region_id
```

Comment: +80 for proper usage of CTEs in all their infinitely recursive glory.

Comment: I think this might work if I change one thing and remove DISTINCT from the count of item_id as I want a to count all items not just all the types of items. I'll let you know and thanks.

Comment: Thanks and Good luck with that!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to include extra columns in the initial part of the recursive query.  That allows you to "pass down" where the recursion started.  In the example below, the extra columns remember the Root_id and Root_name.  That should list all regions and their total item count:

```
; with  Regions as 
        (
        select  Region_id as Root_id
        ,       Region_name as Root_name
        ,       *
        from    @Region
        union all
        select  p.Root_id
        ,       p.Root_name
        ,       c.*
        from    Regions p
        join    @Region c
        on      p.Region_id = c.Parent_id
        )
select  r.Root_name
,       count(distinct si.Item_id) as ItemCount
from    Regions r
left join 
        @RegionStore rs 
on      rs.Region_id = r.Region_id
left join 
        @StoreItems si 
on      si.Store_id = rs.Store_id
group by
        r.Root_name
```

[Working example on SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64626)

Comment: Looks like you need to change SUM into COUNT

Comment: @AndreyGurinov: Thanks, that's indisputably correct, edited :)

Comment: This works also but the site will only let me mark one as the answer - uv - thanks